# How to add a text line to a React styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am learning Styled-component:  I would like my code to render a text line (Your personal trainer) but I do not want to have it in App.js file. How can I do that?

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledTextLine = styled('YOUR PERSONAL TRAINER')`
      color:#333333 100%;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: NeuropoliticalRg-Regular;
      word-spacing:0px;

`;

export default StyledTextLine;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you might want a span:

```
const StyledTextLine = styled.span`
      color:#333333 100%;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-family: NeuropoliticalRg-Regular;
      word-spacing:0px;
`;

const TextLine = () => {
  return <StyledTextLine>YOUR PERSONAL TRAINER</StyledTextLine>
}
```

If you need more help with styled-component feel free to drop on their [docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#getting-started)

If you want to re-use the component pass a prop for a message like this:

```
const TextLine = ({ message }) => {
  return <StyledTextLine>{message}</StyledTextLine>
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reaction. The code is compiled with warnings:( Line 16: 'TextLine' is assigned a value but never used no-unused-vars) and the text line is not rendered( blank page)... – MicheleN 10 mins ago

Comment: @MicheleN cause you need to use it in a render method of your choice:

<TextLine message="YOUR PERSONAL TRAINER" />